# Newline in text file created in jscript via activeXObject

Tags: activex, newline, jscript

Okay from the top:
Using the following code I can create a text file using jscript in an htm file from Internet Explorer via an ActiveX object. Yay!
However, opening the text file in Notepad I noticed new lines appear as mojibake characters (rectangular character) instead of newlines . It's fine in Sublime 2.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myStr = "The self same moment I could pray;\nAnd from my neck so free\nThe Albatross fell off, and sank\nLike lead into the sea.";
var myPath = "C:\\temp\\";
var myTextfile = "Rime.txt"

writeFile(myPath, myTextfile, myStr)
function writeFile(apath, afilename, str)
{ 
  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var outFile = fso.CreateTextFile(apath + afilename, true);
  outFile.WriteLine(str);
  outFile.Close();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also noticed that it doesn't occur when using the following from Photoshop environment (where I normally script from)

```
var txtFile = new File(apath + "/" + afilename);
outFile.open('w');
outFile.writeln(str);
outFile.close();
```

Is this just a quirk (or bonus) of ActiveX? Can I change it so it writes new lines that can be viewed properly in Notepad?

And, yes my Mother did warn me about the dangers of getting involved with ActiveX objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's something wrong with character encoding. Try this instead of `CreateTextFile()`:

```
var outFile = fso.OpenTextFile(apath + afilename, 2, true, 0);
```

2nd arg: `1` = reading, `2` = writing, `8` = appending.

3rd arg: `true` if non-existing file is created, `false` if non-existing file is not created. [optional, default = `false`]

4th arg: `0` = ASCII, `-1` = Unicode, `-2` = system default. [optional, default = `0`]

Comment: I thought it might be something like that but with your new code the new lines still aren't working properly.

Comment: @GhoulFool have you checked "Type of encoding" from NotePad?

Comment: It's currently on ANSI I've found an article [here](http://superuser.com/questions/144447/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-encoding-in-notepad) on how to change it